# Using Mysqldump with root user and blank password

Tags: cmd, mysql

My MySql has a user `root` and blank password (which is default). I am using windows command line in my local machine. Now I would like to use below command with blank password.

```
mysqldump -u root magentotwo > magentotwo2.sql;
```

When I use above command, CMD is asking for password and I press `Enter`. Then CMD showing error. How can I use that command??

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: Thanks @Mattia for your reply. Here is the error `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
dump -u root magentotwo > magentotwo.sql' at line 1`;

Comment: It's mysqldump without spaces, is that a typo?

Comment: @Sevle `mysqldump` is it wrong ??

Comment: no, but according to that error you typed 'mysql dump -u root magentotwo > magentotwo.sql', which is wrong, mysqldump is an executable by itself, no space is needed!

Comment: @Sevle, I copy pasted the error. That is a typo. Thanks

Comment: It seems that you're executing mysqldump in your mysql shell.

Comment: @Mattia, Yes, I am executing mysqldump in your mysql shell.

Comment: mysqldump is a command that you use from your shell, not inside mysql. Type exit and execute your dump. All will work right.